# Using non-blocking iNotify

Tags: c++, file, monitor, inotify

My objective: To monitor a text file for modification without the monitor blocking my program, but forming part of a loop (so checking sequentially) instead.

My head says: Either find a way to run iNotify in non-blocking mode, or thread iNotfiy.

I tried the non-blocking way, and disabled O_NONBLOCK for my iNotify instance using the following command:

```
fcntl (fd, F_SETFL, fcntl (fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
```

However, when I do this and I then attempt:

```
length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
```

It keeps on telling me that for read, a resource is temporarily unavailable.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to achieve what I want to do? Does not need to be this method, but I need the functionality as I am editing a text file with a webserver and want to read modifications into my C++ program to update variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

`EAGAIN` (resource temporarily unavailable) is the expected error status if there is no data available on the file descriptor being read when the file descriptor is set in non-blocking mode. Since you are using a polling loop, you can just try to read again on the next iteration.

Alternatively, you can attempt to use the signal-driven I/O notification for the [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) file descriptor:

> Since Linux 2.6.25, signal-driven I/O notification is available for `inotify` file descriptors; see the discussion of `F_SETFL` (for setting the `O_ASYNC` flag), `F_SETOWN`, and `F_SETSIG` in `fcntl(2)`. The `siginfo_t` structure (described in `sigaction(2)`) that is passed to the signal handler has the following fields set: `si_fd` is set to the `inotify` file descriptor number; `si_signo` is set to the signal number; `si_code` is set to `POLL_IN`; and `POLLIN` is set in si_band.